# Regex - Extrair números

Tags: r, regex, dplyr, stringr

Tenho uma coluna num data.frame que é similar a essa estrutura:

```
d <- structure(list(value = c("           2019s/v282930ahead of print        ", 
"           2018s/v252627         ", "           2017s/v222324         ", 
"           2016s/v192021         ", "           2015s/v161718         "
)), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))
```

Gostaria de transformá-la em 4 outras colunas com as funções `mutate` e `str_extract`, se possível (embora outras sugestões sejam bem-vindas).

As colunas seriam:

Ano - 4 primeiros dígitos

Number_1 - 2 dígitos após o string "s/v"

Number_2 - 2 dígitos subsequentes ao Number_1

Number_3 - 2 dígitos subsequentes ao Number_2

Assim, como resultado para a primeira linha das novas colunas seria

```
 Ano Number_1 Number_2 Number_3
2019       28       29       30
```

O que estou tentando é o seguinte:

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

d %>% 
  mutate(value = str_trim(value), 
        year = str_extract(value, "\\d{4}"),
       Number_1 = str_extract(value, "(s/v)\\d{2}"))
      # Number_2 = str_extract(value, "(s/v)\\d{2}) - Não sei
      # Number_3 = str_extract(value, "(s/v)\\d{2}) - Não sei
```

Alguém poderia dar algumas dicas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## positive look behind

A busca deve fazer uso do operador "positive look behind" `(?<=nao_retorna)vai_retornar`.

Este operador vai começar a busca pela expressão regular apenas depois de encontrar o padrão dentro dos parêntes `(?<=aqui)`

Para ver como funciona esse operador, recomendo rodar o seguinte código:

```
d %>% 
  pull(value) %>% 
  str_view("(?<=s/v)")
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O que a imagem acima mostra, é que o motor de busca vai trazer o que encontrar se vier *imediatamente após* `(s/v)`.

## A resposta

Usando esse operador, podemos resolver o problema com as expressões regulares usadas no código abaixo.

```r
library(tidyverse)
d <- structure(list(value = c("           2019s/v282930ahead of print        ", 
                              "           2018s/v252627         ", "           2017s/v222324         ", 
                              "           2016s/v192021         ", "           2015s/v161718         "
)), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))

d %>% 
  mutate(value = str_trim(value), 
         year = str_extract(value, "\\d{4}"),
         Number_1 = str_extract(value, "(?<=s/v)\\d{2}"),
         Number_2 = str_extract(value, "(?<=s/v\\d{2})\\d{2}"),
         Number_3 = str_extract(value, "(?<=s/v\\d{4})\\d{2}")
  )
#> # A tibble: 5 x 5
#>   value                       year  Number_1 Number_2 Number_3
#>   <chr>                       <chr> <chr>    <chr>    <chr>   
#> 1 2019s/v282930ahead of print 2019  28       29       30      
#> 2 2018s/v252627               2018  25       26       27      
#> 3 2017s/v222324               2017  22       23       24      
#> 4 2016s/v192021               2016  19       20       21      
#> 5 2015s/v161718               2015  16       17       18
```

<sup>Created on 2020-04-24 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: perfeito Tomás! Muito Obrigado! Aproveitando a deixa de sua excelente explicação, tem algum material para indicar (preferencialmente em português) para estudar regex aplicado ao R? Estou vendo algumas coisas, mas não tinha visto ainda o " look behind". De qualquer forma, super valeu!

Comment: Regex no [tag:R] é meio parecido com regex no [tag:perl]. Recomendo brincar no [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/)

Comment: Tem [esse material](https://www.curso-r.com/material/stringr/#header-expressoes-regulares) aqui também

Comment: Vou dar uma olhada, valeu!